# linux - adding a user

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this code but it is not compiling correctly. I want to create a user with a default shell of bin/sh with the group adults. Any suggestions?

Command: `useradd -s /bin/sh –g adults michael`

- Thank you.

Comment: welcome to [so]: this is a *programmers' forum*, for system administrative tasks like creating users, you might want to ask on [su] or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I wonder how you *compile* this code; in any case you should check `man useradd`

Comment: ...to be clear, `useradd` is not a bash command; it's a UNIX utility, and can be started by any shell or no shell at all (ie. from C, Perl or Python) without changing its function, usage or behavior. This is thus neither a bash question nor a shell question in general.

Comment: Also, when asking this question in a more topical place, you should include the *exact error* you receive from your code.

Comment: when you say *it is not compiling correctly*, you should give the errors you're getting, and how you're calling it.

Comment: Preferably you should replace `/bin/sh` with `/bin/bash` because that's the shell you want. Besides, all users can access the shell so that bit of code is rather redundant.

Comment: @Poriferous, how do you know which shell the OP wants? I mean, it's unusual to prefer baseline POSIX sh for interactive use, but "unusual" is not "impossible".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I read the line: `I want to create a user with a default shell of bin/sh`. At any rate, it's down to the user to decide. Regardless, the code he has posted works fine.

Comment: @Poriferous, ...yes, the user said "bin/sh", yet you insist they really want bash -- hence my failure to grok.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I do insist that they should use bash because it's the default shell in Linux. It also addresses certain flaws in `/bin/sh` and has more features than `/bin/sh`. Unless you want to program for embedded systems, bash is the way to go.

Comment: @Poriferous, maybe the OP is writing tools to be run on systems that only have ash, and wants to be sure that testing code on their local shell will guarantee that it works on the target. "You were simply wrong when you said you want X" is tremendously presumptuous, in ways that "you ought to want Y instead" isn't.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did not ask for your input, but if you have something useful to commit to this question then I suggest you do so rather than questioning what answers people give. We can take this discussion elsewhere if arguments satisfy you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the code given is not being *compiled*, but rather executed by a shell. Then your command is perfectly fine, given that the `adults` group already exists before you type the command into your shell.

So without error, or more context, nobody will be able to tell you more than what I'm telling you:

**there's no issue with your command**.

Comment: I'd argue this to be more a set of comments than an answer.

Comment: Well, there's an answer here: *there's no issue with your command*! ☺

Comment: sorry, I am new to this. I apologize for the lack of detail.

Comment: There's obviously *some* kind of issue, the OP just isn't telling us enough to identify it. Maybe they're running without sufficient privileges, maybe the group doesn't exist, maybe they're using options for a `useradd` version other than what their distro provides. The question isn't answerable in its present state; posting an "answer" that says as much makes the question show up as, well, having an answer -- when it actually doesn't.

Comment: Or maybe he's trying to compile a shell script with `gcc` :-D But with the information we got, the only thing we can tell is that there's no issue. If he details his question, I might either delete or update my answer (depending on whether I'm around or not)